# How to clone user in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Have a need for a sql query which will do cloning of Oracle user. As source I have user which has all necessary privileges. I wonder if it is possible to create the same one, but with different username in the same database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Briefly (from [here](http://www.oraclealchemist.com/news/trick-1-copying-users-the-right-way/))

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', '...') FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','...') FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','...') FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','...') FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_granted_DDL('TABLESPACE_QUOTA', '...') FROM dual;
```

Then just replace the username with the new one you want to create.

Comment: PS. If you have java permissions, network ACLs etc, they may need some additional code.

Comment: this is the perfect set of DDL to clone the user , thank you @Gary Myers