# Does SQLDeveloper have a tool to copy/clone users like Toad?

Tags: oracle, toad, oracle-sqldeveloper

Does SQLDeveloper have a Toad-like tool to copy/clone an Oracle database user?

If not, I'll resort to: [How to Clone a User in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468173/how-to-clone-user-in-oracle)

Comment: Oracle Enterprise Manager for 10g - the java app distributed witht he client - does have "Create like..." functionality that can be used to copy a user and his/her rights and privileges.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In version 3 there is a DBA view.  It can be displayed or hidden using the view menu.
Once you have it displayed open the connection in the DBA section.
Drill down to Security->Users and right click on the user you want to copy.
The option you are looking for is create like.

Comment: Bingo! Just what I was looking for. Thanks Todd!

Comment: Just a quick note: copy object privileges is right there on the first tab, but is _not_ selected by default ( https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/12/trick-getting-all-the-privileges-grants-for-a-user/ )