# oracle export and import only user and their roles

Tags: oracle, import, export

I have two question about oracle export and import.

First of all,I want to export only user and their roles not tables,trigger and other object Later import user

How i can do?

Other question is while importing operation, can i get error?Because, which object importing early roles or user? Unless importing roles, user can't assign roles?

Answer (score 0):

You must be using ddl statements, look [How to clone user in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468173/how-to-clone-user-in-oracle) and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30337/duplicate-an-oracle-database-user ,and if you are using SQL Navigator, you can select user in the tree (press F12) and press Ctrl+D